# SQL Ranking Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSu80.png)

I want to rank the Batting Averages and Overall in 2013, but not sure of the function:

```
Select playerID, yearID, Batting_average, teamID, lgID 

RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Batting_average DESC) AS BattingAverageRank

From Material_Batting

where yearID = 2013

order by Batting_average;
```

tried the `RANK ( ) OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )` but didnt work

Comment: what was the query you tried ? what didn't work, any error ? what is the expected output?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the desired output? also, what output did you get when you tried?

Comment: RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Batting_average DESC) AS BattingAverageRank

Tried this but got Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @LebronJames Your query is syntactically correct, so you shouldn't get that error. Something's fishy here, do you have other queries running along with this?

Comment: @LebronJames, you just forgot to put a comma between `lgID` and `RANK` : `..teamID, lgID RANK() ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT playerID
    ,yearID
    ,Batting_average
    ,franchName
    ,rank() OVER (ORDER BY batting_average DESC) Batting_average_rank
FROM Material_Batting
WHERE yearID = 2013
ORDER BY Batting_average
```